# viewDidLoad called before prepareForSegue finishes

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, viewdidload

I was under the impression that viewDidLoad will be called AFTER prepareForSegue finishes.  This is even how Hegarty teaches his Stanford class (as recently as Feb 2013).

However, for the first time today, I have noticed that viewDidLoad was called BEFORE prepareForSegue was finished.  Therefore, the properties that I was setting in prepareForSegue were not available to the destinationViewController within the destinations viewDidLoad method.

This seems contrary to expected behavior.

***UPDATE***

I just figured out what was going on.  In my destinationViewController I had a custom setter that would reload the tableView each time the "model" was updated:

```
DestinationViewController    
- (void)setManagedObjectsArray:(NSArray *)managedObjectsArray
    {
        _managedObjectsArray = [managedObjectsArray copy];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

It turns out, since the destinationViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController...calling 'self.tableView' forces the view to load.  According to Apple's documentation, calling the view property of a view controller can force the view to load.  The view of a UITableViewController is the tableView.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Therefore, in prepareForSegue the following line was forcing the view of the destinationViewController to load:

```
vc.managedObjectsArray = <custom method that returns an array>;
```

To fix the problem, I changed the custom setter of the destinationViewController's model to:

```
- (void)setManagedObjectsArray:(NSArray *)managedObjectsArray
    {
        _managedObjectsArray = [managedObjectsArray copy];
        if ([self isViewLoaded]) {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
```

This will only reload the tableView if the tableView is on screen.  Thus not forcing the view to load during prepareForSegue.

If anyone objects to this process, please share your thoughts.  Otherwise, I hope this prevents a long sleepless night for someone.

Comment: How do you know viewDidLoad was called? Can you share some code?

Comment: I suspect `prepareForSegue` is in fact the function that (directly or indirectly) calls `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 25):

I had run into similar confusions in the past.  The general rules of thumb that I learned are:

1. prepareForSegue is called before destination VC's viewDidLoad
2. viewDidLoad is called only after ALL outlets are loaded
3. Do not attempt to reference any destination VC's outlets in source VC's prepareForSegue.

Another lesson learned with regards to prepareForSegue is to avoid redundant processing. For example, if you already segue a tableView cell to a VC via storyboard, you could run into similar race condition if you attempt to process BOTH tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue.  One can avoid such by either utilizing manual segue or forgo any processing at didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: In fact if you access to outlets in `initWithCoder:`, it implicitly calls `viewDidLoad` method before calling `prepareForSegue:`. thanks @Hampde123 for your comment which help me on my way

Comment: How does one pass data between view controllers if we follow these rules?

Answer (score 3):

Thought I'd add a little explanation on what happened here:

`prepareForSegue` is called before the view is displayed

`viewDidload` is called the first time the view is accessed (view is lazy loaded).

**What probably happened is that you accessed the `view` in `prepareForSegue` triggering the view loading manually.**

Usually the flow is:

1. `preformSegue`
2. `prepareForSegue`
3. `ViewController` is added to the hierarchy
4. `viewDidLoad`.

But what probably happened in your case is:

1. `preformSegue`
2. `prepareForSegue`
3. |— In `prepareForSegue` you access the `view`
4. |— `view` is automatically loaded => `viewDidLoad` is invoked
5. Return from `performSegue`
6. ViewController is added to the hierarchy, no `viewDidLoad` (already called)

So yes usually the `view` property is not accessed before the `ViewController` is added to the hierarchy, but if it is, `viewDidLoad` can be triggered earlier.

Comment: This makes sense, but then how do you pass arguments to the new view if not from prepareForSegue?

Comment: You can still do it, but you need to set the arguments before accessing the view

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing, helped me figure my problem out.

In my case, the destinationViewController is a UITabBarController and modifying it's viewControllers Array triggered the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController;
    tabBarController.viewControllers = ...
    tabBarController.something = something;
}
```

in the viewDidLoad I needed the *something* attribute to be set, so I had to move it up:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController;
    tabBarController.something = something;
     tabBarController.viewControllers = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the simple solution is to place

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

in `viewWillAppear`:

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my dynamic cell which showed a modal when selected. `prepareForSegue` was executed before `didSelect:atIndexPath`. What helped me was that in the storyboard I reassigned the segue to start from the controller and not the dynamic cell prototype. I solved the race condition (?) and everything is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

In my case setting destination presentationController's delegate in prepareSegue caused viewDidLoad to be called.
I moved
segue.destination.presentationController?.delegate = self
to the end of prepareSegue:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)     {
    // do stuff ....
    segue.destination.presentationController?.delegate = self
     }
```