# Pass variable to view controller before viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I perform a segue which is defined in the Storyboard to open a new view controller. I need to configure the destination view controller of the segue in a special state where some of it's buttons does not needed to be displayed.

I know that I can do this by setting a variable on this controller in my source view controller's `-prepareForSegue:sender:`. The problem with this is, that firstly it instantiates the controller, so it's `-viewDidLoad:` will run, then only after can I set anything on it.

I can't create the controller entirely from code, because it's user interface is in Storyboard. `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` also calls `-viewDidLoad` first obviously.

I could probably use a semaphore and add the initialization code into my destination controller's `-viewWillAppear`, but that's ugly, it has to be some more elegant way to do this than doing a check every time the view appears. (My settings need to be done only once.)

Is there some way to pass variables into the controller before it's `-viewDidLoad` runs?

**EDIT**: It looks like this happens only if I trigger the segue from code using `-performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: Why not set these buttons to be hidden by default, then turn them on or not in viewDidLoad? You can then control what gets displayed.

Comment: That does not change anything. Hiding or showing them needs to happen in viewDidLoad.

Comment: So your issue is that you cannot override `viewDidLoad`, rather than you asking to somehow pass and perform configurations before that method gets called. This was a bit unclear to me. My bad.

Comment: My problem is, that I want to use viewDidLoad for setting up my view (because it needs to be done only once), and I can't do that, because I don't have the values of my variables, which I would use to set it up (they will be set after viewDidLoad).

Answer (score 1):

On my machine and on iOS 8.0 and iOS 9.0, viewDidLoad is called after prepareForSegue. So, something like the following worked for my test case of your answer.

In your source controller:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    TimViewController * controller = segue.destinationViewController;

    if( [controller isKindOfClass:[TimViewController class]] )
        controller.name = @"tim";
}
```

In your destination controller (TimViewController):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.

    NSLog( @"view did load %@", self.name );
}
```

Add a segue (a show segue) from your source control to the destination view controller.

Output:

```
2015-09-17 19:09:04.351 Test[51471:7984717] view did load tim
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Ok, I have created a test project for this, and you are partially right. `-prepareForSegue:` definitely runs before `-viewDidLoad` but only if the segue is invoked by Storyboard. If you trigger it from code using `-performSegueWithIdentifier:`, it works differently. See my test project here: https://github.com/gklka/SegueTest

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion here. `-prepareForSegue:sender:` gets called before `-viewDidLoad` gets called. Please double check your implementation.

**Edit:**

May be [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147597/viewdidload-called-before-prepareforsegue-finishes) will help you understand this and one of the mentioned cases fall in your case.